# I don't know how to format this matrix as text

Tags: python

Example:

```
first = [['1 1 1', '1 1 1', '1 1 1']
t = [' '.join([str(int(num)) for num in row]) for row in first]
print('\n'.join(t))
```

Output:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

So far so good.. but...

I have this:

```
data = [['2 2 2', '2 2 2', '2 2 2'], 
        ['3 3 3', '3 3 3', '3 3 3'], 
        ['4 4 4', '4 4 4', '4 4 4'], 
        ['5 5 5', '5 5 5', '5 5 5']]
```

And I want to print it as..

```
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
```

But with more dimensions I don't know how to do it, thanks for your time

---

Solution:

```
data = [['2 2 2', '2 2 2', '2 2 2'], 
        ['3 3 3', '3 3 3', '3 3 3'], 
        ['4 4 4', '4 4 4', '4 4 4'], 
        ['5 5 5', '5 5 5', '5 5 5']]
print('\n'.join("   ".join([num for num in row]) for row in zip(*data)))
```

Output:

```
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
```

Thanks to @ThierryLathuille for the **zip** mention

Comment: Probably relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: As you have to print row by row and your data is column by column, have you considered using `zip`?

Comment: Your edit shows you have the solution: loop over your list

Comment: @ThierryLathuille thank you for the `zip`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

###### Algorithm:

- print the 0th index of every row separated by tabs
- print the 1st index of every row separated by tabs

...and so on.

###### Code:

```
data = [['2 2 2', '2 2 2', '2 2 2'], 
        ['3 3 3', '3 3 3', '3 3 3'], 
        ['4 4 4', '4 4 4', '4 4 4'], 
        ['5 5 5', '5 5 5', '5 5 5']]
for i in range(len(data[0])):
    print("\t".join([data[j][i] for j in range(len(data))]))
```

###### Output:

```
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution that I think is very easy to understand:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

data = [['2 2 2', '2 2 2', '2 2 2'],
        ['3 3 3', '3 3 3', '3 3 3'],
        ['4 4 4', '4 4 4', '4 4 4'],
        ['5 5 5', '5 5 5', '5 5 5']]

for c in range(0, len(data[0])):
    print("  ".join(row[c] for row in data))
```

Output:

```
2 2 2  3 3 3  4 4 4  5 5 5
2 2 2  3 3 3  4 4 4  5 5 5
2 2 2  3 3 3  4 4 4  5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any (explicit) loop, `zip`, `map` and `join` are sufficient:

```
print('\n'.join(map('   '.join, zip(*data))))
```

output:

```
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   5 5 5
```

**Explanation**: `zip(*data)` transposes the data, `map`+`'   '.join` produces the rows, `'\n'.join` assembles the lines into the final text ready for `print`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a format string that will align the columns the way you want to. The advantage here is that you can easily see and adjust the width of the columns.

```
data = [['2 2 2', '2 2 2', '2 2 2'], ['3 3 3', '3 3 3', '3 3 3'], ['4 4 4', '4 4 4', '4 4 4'], ['5 5 5', '5 5 5', '5 5 5']]

format_string = ('{:<{width}}' * len(data[0]))

for t in zip(*data):
    print(format_string.format(*t, width=8))
```

Prints:

```
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4   
2 2 2   3 3 3   4 4 4
```

Adjusting the width is not simple and readable:

```
for t in zip(*data):
    print(format_string.format(*t, width=15))
```

Results in:

```
2 2 2          3 3 3          4 4 4          
2 2 2          3 3 3          4 4 4          
2 2 2          3 3 3          4 4 4
```

You could also dynamically adjust the width based on the input quite easily to allow for a general solution.